# Custom view in MAC OSX app with XIB file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have worked with iOS but I am quite new to MAC OSX development. I am trying to design the screen as shown below in XIB file. I understand the left one is a table view with custom cells in it. What kind of view the bottom tool bar with +/- button is? Also, is the view on the right side is inside Box NSView?

How we do design the similar view with XIB file.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this picture. Hope it helps you to make similar UI in interface builder.

[image]